# Android: Pick up an image from gallery and set the image in the alert dialog

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog

When clicking the floating action button, an alert dialog appears and there is one image view and one image button inside the dialog. By clicking the image button, the screen will move on to the gallery, and after clicking one of the images the gallery closes and the image view should be set with the selected image.

This is what I intended, but with the current code there seems to be a flaw. I managed to go to the gallery, pick up an image and that's it. The selected image is not set on the image view on the dialog.

Here's the code that defines the action on clicking the floating action button.

```
    fabAddACategory = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAddNewCategory);
    fabAddACategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_a_new_category, null);
            ivCategoryImage = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ivCategoryImage);
            final EditText etCategoryTitle = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.etCategoryTitle);

            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManageCategoriesActivity.this)
                    .setView(layout)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.create), null)
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), null)
                    .create();

            alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Button btnCreate = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

                    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String categoryTitle = etCategoryTitle.getText().toString();

                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton ibAdd = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.ibAdd);
                    ibAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent chooseImageFromGallery = new Intent();
                            chooseImageFromGallery.setType("image/*");
                            chooseImageFromGallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                            try {
                                chooseImageFromGallery.putExtra("return-data", true);
                                startActivityForResult(chooseImageFromGallery, PICK_IMAGE);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

And this overridden `onActivityResult()` method below defines the action after choosing an image. According to this part, the new selected image should be set on the image view.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
        if(extra != null) {
            Bitmap picture = extra.getParcelable("data");
            ivCategoryImage.setImageBitmap(picture);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `onActivityResult` ever called when you put breakpoint and debug or using logs?

Comment: Yes, I called a toast in `onActivityResult` method, and it came out when I chose an image in the gallery.

Comment: So `Intent data` parameter is null ?

Comment: Oh I haven't thought about that case. Then what should I modify in that code?

Comment: I'm not saying that `data` must be null but please check that option, also depending on external Image Gallery intent shouldn't be null but `getExtras()` not always return bitmap like you do in code. The best way is to get `Uri` of picked image and load it from contentResolver

Comment: I changed the `onActivityResult` method from using `Bundle` to `Uri` and now it's working. Thanks for the tip.